# Mapping user objects to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sending a mailer using the mandrill API and the to: method needs to be in the following format:

```
[{ email: 'someone@email.com', name: 'Bob Bertly' }, { email: 'other@email.com', name: 'Claire Nayo' }]
```

How can I automatically place all users in this format? my first thought was to have an each do statement going through each user and placing user.name and user.email in their positions, but I couldn't get this to work.

Any guidance would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write a class method using [`serializable_hash`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveModel/Serialization/serializable_hash) like this:

```
def self.to_hash
  all.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
end
```

Then you can get the array of all users by this:

```
User.to_hash
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have your list of users in the 'users' variable and that users have emails & names:

```
users.map do |user|
  {email: user.email, name: user.name}
end
```

will return you an array of hashes as requested.